# Oracle APEX: Searching for a substring

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm struggling with a SQL Query:

I have some text like this:

```
*any text can appear here* input type="hidden" name="f01" value="1524"
```

And what I need is to get the numbers after **value="**, which in this case is **1524**, but it can be more than 4 or less.

I have tried matching the text with REGEXP_SUBSTR, but I'm not familiar with regular expressions...

Comment: In what context? It looks like you are storing your html in the database, which, in  most cases, doesn't make much sense. Usually such values are extracted before being sent to the database.

Comment: *I have some data like this*.... do you mean you have a database table with a column that has values that look like that? What is the type of the column?

Comment: I'm actually using Oracle Application Express (APEX), and I have an item in a page which saves that text. But basically, what I need is to get that value through a SQL Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try that :

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(MY_COLUMN,'.*value="([0-9]+)".*','\1') FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's exactly what I was looking for.